# Overcome/ignore compatibility view IE11 for particular page/site

Tags: iis, internet-explorer-7, ie8-compatibility-mode

I have a sharepoint site and loading an external website in a content page. I have enabled compatibility mode for my sharepoint site, and the external site will not work in IE lower versions. Since i have enabled compatibility view for the site, the external site not loading in iFrame of my content page.

Is it atleast possible to turn off or bypass the compatibility view setting for the particular page? Since i have enabled the compatibility view for the domain, the meta tags are ignored.

I tried to modify the user agent string in URL rewrite also.

Any advise?

Comment: I agree with the suggestion given by @Mahmoud Kubrosli. I tested the suggested code and I found that the page in iframe loaded with the latest IE mode even if the site was added to the compatibility mode. I suggest you can have a test on your side and let us know about your testing results.

Answer (score 0):

I've never tested this with an iframe that has an external reference, 
but if you are talking about one of your site pages, Try to add the follwoing to your config file

```
<location path="Your_Page_Path">
    <system.webServer>
        <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=Edge" />
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```